# Replacing leaf atoms by the 0 in a tree and lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am stuck with the following Prolog code:

```
islist([]).
islist([A|B]) :-
   islist(B).

memb([X|_]).       
memb([Y|Z]) :- 
   islist(Y),
   memb(Y).
memb([_|Z]) :- 
   memb(Z).

deep([],[]).
deep([H|P],[M|N]) :-
   islist(H),
   deep(H,M),
   deep(P,N).
deep([Y|P],[Y|N]) :-
   number(Y),
   deep(P,N).
deep([H|P],[M|N]) :-
   atom(H),
   M is 0,
   deep(P,N).
deep([Y|P],[H|Q]) :-
   not(number(Y)),
   not(islist(Y)),
   not(atom(Y)),
   Y =.. T,
   deep(T,F),
   H =.. F,
   deep(P,Q),
   !.
```

It is giving me fail when I am trying to run it.

I am not able to do this. Please help. I am not understanding where am I wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you're misusing univ/2 (that is (=..)/2). Changing the last clause to

```
deep([Y|P],[H|Q]):-
    not(number(Y)),
    not(islist(Y)),
    not(atom(Y)),
    Y=..[T|YArgs],
    deep(YArgs,HArgs),
    H=..[T|HArgs],
    deep(P,Q),!.
```

you'll get the required behaviour

```
?- deep([14,dog,a(b,27,c(16,[g]))],A).
A = [14, 0, a(0, 27, c(16, [0]))]
```

Note that a cut as last goal of last clause has no effect. It's totally useless, but it's usage is indicative that you need to study a bit more about Prolog execution mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot . This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When I simply took your program, loaded it, ignored the singleton warnings, and traced it, I eventually get:

```
Call: (14) _G2807=..[0, 16, [0]] ? creep
ERROR: =../2: Type error: `atom' expected, found `0' (an integer)
   Exception: (14) _G2807=..[0, 16, [0]] ?
```

So, every time you get a functor, you first decompose it, like this:

```
foo(1, bar) ---> [foo, 1, bar] % in your code: Y=..T
```

You then replace the atoms with 0's:

```
[foo, 1, bar] ---> [0, 1, 0] % in your code: deep(T,F)
```

and then you for some reason try to make a functor again out of it:

```
[0, 1, 0] ---> 0(1, 0) % in your code: H=..F
```

Which of course doesn't work, and it is not what you are after, it seems:

```
foo(1, bar) ---> foo, [1, bar] % Y =.. [Name|Args]
```

Then, you can convert the list only:

```
[1, bar] ---> [1, 0] % deep(Args, Args1)
```

and re-make the term:

```
foo, [1, 0] ---> foo(1, 0) % H =.. [Name|Args1]
```

With these corrections in the program:

```
?- deep([14,dog,a(b,27,c(16,[g]))],A).
A = [14, 0, a(0, 27, c(16, [0]))] ;
false.
```

But you can altogether make the program a bit simpler. First, I don't think you need the `memb/1` you have defined: get rid of it. Then, you can also use another clause in that definition:

```
islist(X) :-
    var(X), !,
    fail.
islist([]).
islist([_|T]) :-
    islist(T).
```

One way to clean up the rest of your code a bit would be to write:

```
deep([], []).
deep([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
    once( deep_1(X, Y) ),
    deep(Xs, Ys).

deep_1(X, Y) :- islist(X), deep(X, Y).
deep_1(X, X) :- number(X).
deep_1(X, 0) :- atom(X).
deep_1(X, Y) :- compound(X),
    X =.. [Name|Args],
    deep(Args, Args1),
    Y =.. [Name|Args1].
```

As you see, at the moment, if you have a variable (or any other non-recognized term), the program will fail:

```
?- deep([14,dog,a(b,27,c(16,[g]))],A).
A = [14, 0, a(0, 27, c(16, [0]))].

?- deep([14,Dog,a(b,27,c(16,[g]))],A).
false.
```

You can easily expand the program by simply adding types:

```
deep_1(X, X) :- string(X).
```

And then:

```
?- deep([14,"Dog",a(b,27,c(16,[g]))],A).
A = [14, "Dog", a(0, 27, c(16, [0]))].

?- deep([14,Dog,a(b,27,c(16,[g]))],A).
false.

?- deep([14,dog,a(b,27,c(16,[g]))],A).
A = [14, 0, a(0, 27, c(16, [0]))].
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing my concept. I am trying this one on NU-prolog. The code is perfect for SW-prolog.